# jQuery mobile list view refresh is not maintaining listview style

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div>
  <ul id="categories" data-role="listview">
    <li>
      <a href="#">England</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery ajax code:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert('Do something called');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Some URL',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert("Before send alert");
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert("Service call complete.");

        },
        success: function (strData) {
            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(strData);
            alert("Service call success." + strData['CategoyKey']);

            $.each(strData.GetCategoriesResult, function (key, value) {
                $('#categories').append('<li><a href=\'#\'>' + value.CategoryDescription + '</a></li>');
            });
            alert('Calling refresh');
            $("#categories").listview("refresh");
        },
        error: function () {

            alert(error());
        }
    });
};
```

I am calling this function on one button click. But i am not able to see listview widget with its style. It looks like a plain list.

Version of jquery JS is jquery-1.11.1.min.js
Version of jquery Mobile JS is jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: make sure you're using unique `id`. for debugging, use `console.log()` rather than `alert()`.

Comment: Hi Omar, I am able to see the list correctly, but its style is not maintained when i refresh. I did not get the meaning of unique id. Did you mean <div> <ul> id?

Comment: try moving `.listview("refresh")` outside `success`, move it to `done` for instance.